# Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment in Google Maps Sample

Tags: android, google-maps

I just download the ADT Bundle, update the eclipse plugin, update the extras and tools folder from the sdk, import google play services and google maps sample from the sdk I have this error

```
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapdemo/com.example.mapdemo.BasicMapDemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.example.mapdemo.BasicMapDemoActivity.onCreate(BasicMapDemoActivity.java:42)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    ... 11 more
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/maps_popup_pointer_button.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0201b7
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1951)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:672)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at maps.e.bm.a(Unknown Source)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at maps.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at maps.e.bh.a(Unknown Source)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at maps.e.bg.a(Unknown Source)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at etu.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    ... 20 more
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/maps_popup_pointer_button.xml from xml type drawable resource ID #0x7f0201b7
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2178)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1946)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    ... 39 more
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable/maps_popup_pointer_button.xml
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2160)
04-02 13:49:26.031: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    ... 40 more
04-02 13:49:26.062: E/android.os.Debug(307): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Some folder from the proyect and lib configuration

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/12sksspx5a42bnq/lNUKGtsUgI#/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.mapdemo"
  android:versionCode="6"
  android:versionName="2.7.0">
  <!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <!-- External storage for caching. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- My Location -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
  <!-- End of copy. -->
  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/demo_title"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <!-- ** You need to replace the key below with your own key. **
         The example key below will not be accepted because it is not linked to the
         certificate which you will use to sign this application.
         See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
         for instructions on how to get your own key. -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyCvGBr5in13NK2********Ttnxj3mrXQy4"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:name=".LegalInfoActivity"
      android:label="@string/legal_info"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".BasicMapDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/basic_map_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".CameraDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/camera_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".CircleDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/circle_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".EventsDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/events_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".GroundOverlayDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/ground_overlay_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".LayersDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/layers_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".LocationSourceDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/location_source_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".MapInPagerDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/map_in_pager_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".MarkerDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/marker_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".MultiMapDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/multi_map_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".MyLocationDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/my_location_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".OptionsDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/options_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".PolygonDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/polygon_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".PolylineDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/polyline_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".ProgrammaticDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/programmatic_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".RawMapViewDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/raw_map_view_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".RetainMapDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/retain_map_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".SaveStateDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/save_state_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".SnapshotDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/snapshot_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".TileCoordinateDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/tile_coordinate_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".TileOverlayDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/tile_overlay_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".UiSettingsDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/ui_settings_demo_label"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".VisibleRegionDemoActivity"
      android:label="@string/visible_region_demo_label"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- This can go anywhere in your layout (see other demos for some examples). -->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

If a create the map via Java like this

```
mapaVirtual = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.map, mapaVirtual, "TAG");
        ft.commit();

        mapaVirtual = new SupportMapFragment() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                GoogleMap map = mapaVirtual.getMap();
                if (map != null)
                {
                    mapa = mapaVirtual.getMap();
                    mapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                    mapa.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
                        {

                        }
                    });

                    mapa.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
                    {
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
```

Same error

**UPDATE**

Some testing

Samsung G3 - Mini with 4.1.2 Google Play services client version: 3159100 > Works

Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 with 4.1.1 Google Play services cliente version: 3159100 > Not works

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error fragment google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770314/error-fragment-google-maps) You may not post a **duplicate of your own question from two days ago** the stack trace of which **shows the exact same problem**.  Instead, edit your original question to improve it with anything you have learned since then.

Comment: the delete that question becuase this is better explained. thanks!

Comment: -1 No.  That question has meaningful responses, which would then be lost.  Delete this one and undelete and improve that one.

Comment: that question has no answers. Only my reviews

Comment: please do not downvote this one. I really need a answer

Comment: You still shouldn't be resubmitting the same question.  If you want one without downvotes, use the original.

Comment: the error is the same but the origin is different. this one is from a google sample (easy to reproduce and see the configuration to everyone)

Comment: Great - you now know how to fix your original question.